# THREE: How to get smooth corners of custom shape

Tags: three.js, webgl

I have created a custom shape
[image: a custom shape]

How do I give it some rounded edges to give it a more natural look.

Using subdevision does not seem to be a suitable solutions without changing the geometry.

Comment: Have you tried `Subdivision` modifier ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If subdivision doesn't do it for you it might be simpler to create the geometry in a 3D editor(like [Blender](http://www.blender.org/), 3dsmax,C4D,maya,etc.) and apply a Chamfer modifier to chamfer the edges. You should then be able to triangulate the model and export an obj for three.js use.

This is faster for now than porting (or writing from scratch) a generic geometry chamfer modifier for three.js

Answer (score 1):

Create renderer instance with antialias param, set it true.

```
renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({ antialias: true })
```